# Form input showing image insted of text value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form which i am using to update adds on my site, I am filling input value with existing adds but there is a problem in form it is showing adds images instead of text value.

I need to update adds link by replacing the link value in input field.

Input field has value as

```
<input name="addtop" type="text" value="<a href="http://www.xxyy.com/4g...." target="_blank"  <img src="http://www.xxyy.com/h4...."/></a>" />
```

when i try to load page it shows image in input field instead of text as:

```
<a href="http://www.xxyy.com/4g...." target="_blank"  <img src="http://www.xxyy.com/h4...."/> ></a>`
```

Please see how can I make input to show links in  value instead of images.

Comment: I think there is some typo errors .... 1. Where is your <a tag ">" closing part. 

Instead of this value="<a href="http://www.xxyy.com/4g...."
It should be value="<a href='http://www.xxyy.com/4g....'"

Comment: @Vivek yes there was a typo error, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for whatever sets the `value=` of those `<input type="text">` boxes.

It will take image tags and HTML and render them as HTML entities that will safely be place in that text box.

Then when you want to process the contents of that for, just use [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to decode the HTML entities.

**UPDATE:** Your first attempt to fix this—shown in the comments—is this:

```
<input name="addtop" type="text" value="htmlspecialchars(<?php echo $addtop?>)" />
```

That is just incorrect. [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is a PHP function. So you need to put it in the `<?php … ?>` area.  It should be:

```
<input name="addtop" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($addtop)?>" />
```

Comment: I try to use it like this `<input name="addtop" type="text" value="htmlspecialchars(<?php echo $addtop ?>)" />` but it is still showing add image.